# How exactly do respirators seal out pathogens?

Tags: discussion

[Moderator Carey Gregory](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/how-exactly-do-respirators-seal-out-pathogens?noredirect=1#comment39533_20926) unilaterally rejected the migration of [How exactly do respirators seal out pathogens?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20926/14) by Biology SE's moderators. Note that I didn't migrate it.

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because construction of respirators isn't medical science either. – [Carey Gregory♦](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/805/carey-gregory) [5 hours ago](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/how-exactly-do-respirators-seal-out-pathogens?noredirect=1#comment39533_20926)

Was this question closed correctly? My question doesn't involve the "construction of respirators". It involves respirators' protection against pathogens.

Comment: I was just about to post the same question, thanks.  +1

Comment: maybe it's better suited to physics ?

Answer (score 3):

Your question *does* involve the construction of the mask. You're asking "How does this device work?" and that's an engineering question, not a medical question. A doctor doesn't need to know a single thing about how respirators work to know what they do and how and when to use one, and I doubt if much of anything taught in medical school would train a doctor to design an effective respirator.

So no, it's not on topic here. The Biology mods were doing you a favor by migrating it here instead of just closing it, but they were mistaken. That happens. I've migrated questions that were closed by the receiving mods. It's not a noteworthy event.

What I recommend is that you look at your question, read the reasons given for migrating/closing it, look at the published guidelines for both sites, and then reformulate it to fit one of them. Or choose a more appropriate site. Getting your question closed on two sites suggests you're not paying attention to site guidelines.

Comment: You wrote "Getting your question closed on two sites suggests you're not paying attention to site guidelines." I had written: "Note that I didn't migrate it." Aren't you faulting me for the migration here?